# Firebase, angular 2 and E2E testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, firebase

I was wondering if there was a way to mock the remote firebase backend while E2E testing using firebase and angular 2 ?

Does it exist something like mockbackend while using angular 1, but for firebase ?

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.addMockModule('httpMocker', function() {
      angular.module('httpMocker', ['ngMockE2E'])
      .run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET(
          'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
          .respond([
          {
            albumId: 1,
            id: 1,
            title: "accusamus beatae ad",
            url: "http://placehold.it/600/92c952",
            thumbnailUrl: "http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"
          }
          ])

      })
    })
  });
```

Comment: I think Firebase call could be reduced to generating some `Observables` with the help of Rxjs, take a look here https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md

Comment: I also wish there was something like mock http for firebase. The best I could find ultil now is to use a test harness to simulate firebase as suggested in this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html.

I think it is a bit complicated because of websockets and the proprietary Firebase Wire Protocol.